# JQuery quiz app not resetting to show the next answer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a math app in JavaScript/JQuery, there will be a timer that gives the user 3 seconds to answer math questions given to them at random, if they don't answer in 3 seconds the user will lose. I can't get the next random question to display when the user selects the right answer.

I put all of the questions in an array of objects. Then I created a function that takes a random Math function as the parameter. The random function randomly picks between the indices in the array of objects.

I thought by calling this random function again in my selectAnswer() that it would reset the information fr the current question and display the next question at random. But it's only appending the current question again..

I am a beginner so my code might not be th greatest! I'm open to any insight!!
You'll also notice, that the event to reload the page when the start over button is clicked is not firing correctly. I'm working on that.

```js
const questions = [
    {
        question: '80 * 20',
        answ: 80 * 20,
        answers: [
            { text: 1600 },
            { text: -1600 },
            { text: 16 },
            { text: 160 },

        ]
    },
    {
        question: '80 / 20',
        answ: 80 / 20,
        answers: [
            { text: '-4', correct: false },
            { text: '50', correct: false },
            { text: '4', correct: true },
            { text: '40', correct: false },

        ]
    },


    {
        question: '80 + 20',
        answ: 80 + 20,
        answers: [
            { text: '-100', correct: false },
            { text: '1000', correct: false },
            { text: '10', correct: false },
            { text: '100', correct: true },
        ]
    },

    {
        question: '80 - 20',
        answ: 80 - 20,
        answers: [
            { text: '66', correct: false },
            { text: '60', correct: true },
            { text: '600', correct: false },
            { text: '20', correct: false },
        ]
    },

    {
        question: '8 * -2',
        answ: 8 * -2,
        answers: [
            { text: '66', correct: false },
            { text: '666', correct: false },
            { text: '-16', correct: true },
            { text: '16', correct: false },
        ]
    },

    {
        question: '-2 + 8',
        answ: -2 + 8,
        answers: [
            { text: '-6', correct: false },
            { text: '66', correct: false },
            { text: '600', correct: false },
            { text: '6', correct: true },
        ]
    },

    {
        question: '14 - 66',
        answ: 14 - 66,
        answers: [
            { text: '52', correct: false },
            { text: '54', correct: false },
            { text: '-52', correct: true },
            { text: '-54', correct: false },
        ]
    },

    {
        question: '103 * 33',
        answ: 103 * 33,
        answers: [
            { text: '3502', correct: true },
            { text: '3509', correct: false },
            { text: '3503', correct: false },
            { text: '3507', correct: false },
        ]
    },

    {
        question: '165 / 33',
        answ: 165 / 33,
        answers: [
            { text: '33', correct: true },
            { text: '15', correct: false },
            { text: '5', correct: false },
            { text: '25', correct: false },
        ]
    },

    {
        question: '88 * 28',
        answ: 88 * 28,
        answers: [
            { text: '2624', correct: false },
            { text: '2462', correct: false },
            { text: '2464', correct: true },
            { text: '2426', correct: false },
        ]
    }

]







$(() => {
    // GRABBING HTML ELEMENTS
    const $startBtn = $("#start-btn")
    const $timeLeft = $("#time-left")
    const $quitBtn = $("#quit-btn")
    const $secondsLeft = $("#seconds-left")
    const $questionContainerElement = $("#question-container")
    const $questionElement = $("#question")
    const $answerButtonElement = $("#answer-buttons")
    $secondsLeft.hide()
    $quitBtn.hide()
    let $buttons;
    let mathAnsw;
    // CREATING VARIABLES FOR RANDOM FUNCTION ANCD URRENT QUESTION
    let shuffledQuestions, currentQuestionIndex
    let timeLeft = 3
   
    // START BUTTON FUNCTIONALITY
    // HIDES START MENU WHEN FIRED
    // INVOKES RANDOM FUNCTION 
    $startBtn.click(() => {
        $secondsLeft.fadeIn(900)
        $quitBtn.fadeIn(900)
        $startBtn.fadeOut(900)
        // countDown()
        console.log("started")
        $startBtn.hide()
        // SORTS THROUGH THE ARRAY OF QUESTIONS
        shuffledQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5)
        currentQuestionIndex = 0;
        $questionContainerElement.show()
        showQuestion(shuffledQuestions[currentQuestionIndex])
        mathAnsw = questions[currentQuestionIndex].answ
        console.log("the answer", mathAnsw)
    })
    // NEXT BUTTON FUNCTIONALITY
    // INVOKES SHOWQUESTION() EVERYTIME FIRED
    const setNext = () => {
        showQuestion(question)
        console.log(questions)
        // resetState()
    }
    $quitBtn.click(() => {
        location.reload(true)
    })
    // CURRENT QUESTION
    // APPEND CURRENT QUESTION TO THE QUESTION BOX
    const showQuestion = (question) => {
        $questionElement.append(`<h2 class="text-center">${questions[currentQuestionIndex].question}</h2>`)
        console.log(questions[currentQuestionIndex].question)
        // POPULATING ANSWERS
        const AnswersArray = question.answers
        let value
        for (x in AnswersArray) {
            $buttons = $(`<button id="answer${x}"class="btn" value='${questions[currentQuestionIndex].answers[x].text}'>${questions[currentQuestionIndex].answers[x].text}</button>`)
            $answerButtonElement.append($buttons)
        }
        selectAnswer()
    }
    // ANSWER
    const selectAnswer = () => {
        $('.btn').each(function () {
            $(this).on("click", function () {
                let $value = $(this).attr('value')
                let value = Number($value)
                console.log(value)
                console.log(mathAnsw)
                if (value === mathAnsw) {
                    console.log('correct!!')
                    showQuestion(shuffledQuestions[currentQuestionIndex])

                } else {
                    $("#question-container").replaceWith("<h1>You Lost</h1>")
                    $quitBtn.replaceWith("<button id='start-over'>Start Over</button>")
                    console.log("wrong")
                }
            })
        })
    }
    $("#start-over").click(() => {
        location.reload(true)
        console.log("clicked")
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fast Math</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="../fast-math/lib/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


    <div class="container">
        <h3 id="seconds-left">Seconds Left: <span id="time-left"></span></h3>
        <div id="question-container" class="hide">
            <div id="question">Question</div>
            <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">start</button>
            <button id="quit-btn" class="quit-btn btn">quit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="mathProblems.js"></script>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: If i understood correctly, you should increment `currentQuestionIndex` before eexecuting `showQuestion(shuffledQuestions[currentQuestionIndex])` again. If you don't, you'd have the same index, therefore the same question. btw your snippet doesn't seam to work

Comment: When I checked the snippet it didn't work properly unless I ran it on a full page. Have you tried that? 

I was able to get the next question to show up by incrementing currentQuestionIndex before executing the function, but now the previous question is replaced with undefined.  Is there a way I can reset the current question so the next question will be the only question rendered??

Comment: in nextQuestion, you can add a function that deletes everything in your question container: `$idkTheNameQuestionContainer.html = ""` It will erase everyhing inside that element

Comment: Do you mean the html() manipulation method?

Comment: yeah i don't remember exactly, it's been a while since I used jquery

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help! (=